# What is the best way to programmatically convert Ensembl ids from one release to other? e.g. transcript ids from release 75 to 100

Tags: gene, ensembl, identifiers, conversion

3 solutions that I had to unfortunately rule out.

**Potential solution #1**

As far as I know, the conventional way is to do this is by using CCDS ids (e.g. using biomart). However, the issue is that, as I see on the [CCDS project page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/CCDS/CcdsBrowse.cgi?REQUEST=SHOW_STATISTICS), the last release of CCDS ids was made almost 3 years ago (!) and it seems to be compatible with Ensembl release 92. Then how should one convert ids to the latest Ensembl release e.g. 100?

| CCDS Release | Species | NCBI Annotation Release | Ensembl Annotation Release | Assembly Name | Assembly ID | Made Public |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | Homo sapiens | 109 | 92 | GRCh38.p12 | GCF_000001405.38 | 06/14/2018 |

**Potential solution #2**

I am also aware of Ensembl's [ID History Converter](http://useast.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Tools/IDMapper). However, I am looking for a programmatic approach. Also, I noticed that if I try to convert ~>20K ids with ID History Converter, in my experience, there is always some issue. e.g. an error I got when I tried to convert ~70K ensembl transcript ids.
[image]

As a side note, I wonder why this ID conversion functionality is not available via Ensembl's REST API. To me, id conversion seems to be a basic enough task that almost every bioinformatician has to do. So it would be immensely helpful to be someday able to do this programmatically using Ensembl's mighty a REST API.

**Potential solution #3**

Finally, as another potential solution, over at Ensembl's FTP website, located within the directory of the release to which I am interested in converting my ids to (release 100, target release), I saw that according to a [README file](http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-100/README), "ensembl_archive_" directory should contain "Data on historical Ensembl releases". So, I wondered if this directory contains a map between ids from different releases. However, without any extra info about column names, contents, file formats etc, I couldn't really figure out how to use those files. So, I had to rule this one out too.

```
Index of /pub/release-100/mysql/ensembl_archive_100/
../
CHECKSUMS                                          26-Mar-2020 14:31                 132
ens_release.txt.gz                                 26-Mar-2020 14:31                1098
ensembl_archive_100.sql.gz                         26-Mar-2020 14:31                 943
release_species.txt.gz                             26-Mar-2020 14:31               39620
species.txt.gz                                     26-Mar-2020 14:31                6669
```

Of note, I saw a similar "mysql" directory over at the directory of the release whose ids I want to convert (source release): `http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/grch37/release-100/mysql/homo_sapiens_core_100_37/` . However, again, I do not understand its contents without any extra information.

So, finally, I am not sure what is the best way to programmatically convert Ensembl ids from between different releases. As a test case scenario, I want to convert all the protein_coding transcript ids from GRCh37 (release 75) to GRCh38 (release 100). If anybody has any suggestions about this, please kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The ID history converter is available as a [Perl script](https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-tools/tree/release/103/scripts/id_history_converter).

This script accesses these [MySQL tables](http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/core/core_schema.html#gene_archive), so you could query these tables directly.

Note that the mapping session is only one release at a time, so you would need to run 25 queries to go from release 75 to 100.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To use the perl script, I wonder if there is any tutorial to refer to. I am particularly interested in knowing how to "tell" the script to convert from a given specific release to other specific release e.g. from 75 to 76.

Comment: It just gives you the whole history, you would need to parse out the releases you want.

Comment: `IDmapper.pl` does the job, but I wish there was an easy way to install its dependency called `Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry`. I feel that perhaps a wrapper of sorts, for example in the Anaconda system, would be immensely helpful. (Please somebody make it happen! :D )

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it programmatically using the biomaRt package (your potential solution #1):

```
library(biomaRt)
library(dplyr)

mart37 <- useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
                  host    = "grch37.ensembl.org",
                  path    = "/biomart/martservice",
                  dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

mart38 <- useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL",
                  path    = "/biomart/martservice",
                  dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

#pick all genes on chr22 from build 37 as a test dataset::
out37 <- getBM(attributes = c('hgnc_symbol', 'chromosome_name',
                              'ensembl_gene_id', 'ensembl_transcript_id', 'ccds'),
                  filters = c('chromosome_name'),
                  values = list("22"),
                  mart = mart37) %>% #empty string CCDS ID's
  filter(ccds != "")

#NOTE:: to check which filters can be used to query mart37, run this command:
#View(listFilters(mart37))

out38 <- getBM(attributes = c('hgnc_symbol', 'chromosome_name',
                              'ensembl_gene_id', 'ensembl_transcript_id', 'ccds'),
                        filters = c('ccds'),
                        values = list(out37$ccds),
                        mart = mart38)
```

What this does is query the build 38 DB via the CCDS ID's of build 37. You can include other variables in this `out38` dataframe by simply adding to the attributes argument above. And in order to see all of the potential variables that can be included, you just have to run `View(listFilters(mart37))` or `View(listFilters(mart38))`, depending on which build you are interested in.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: your solution could indeed be useful. I am just curious which ensembl release numbers are used when `mart37` and `mart38` were built. Is there a way to specify that?

Comment: `mart37` corresponds to the GRCh37 release, while `mart38` corresponds to GRCh38. This is specified in the `host=` argument in the code above. `mart38` is the default, and so is not specified. Does this answer your question?

Comment: P.S. if you're referring to the version number of the ensembl release, you can obtain this by adding `'ensembl_gene_id_version'` to the `attributes` array in the code above.

Comment: By Ensembl release number I meant [version numbers of the assemblies maintained by ensembl](https://www.ensembl.info/category/01-release/), e.g. release 75 corresponds to GRCh37 for human genome.

Comment: `ensembl_gene_id_version` could be useful if it is possible to know to which release that belongs to. e.g. how would I know if `x.3` id belongs to genome release 90 or 91? To get this information, I would have to run 'Ensembl IDmapper' which I would like to avoid, because of the issue I mentioned in my question.